# No log in http.sys while I get 503 error for my asp.net mvc application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, http-status-code-503

After I publish my asp.net mvc application to IIS, for a while it shows 503 error to users and after a minutes it become Ok. But I can not find any log in http.sys (%Systemroot%\System32\LogFiles\HTTPERR) or Event view logs.

In addition, when I try to use "Debug Diag Tool " the app stops serving and again throws 503 error.

So is there a way to find the cause of the error ?

Updated
[image]

Comment: A screenshot of the 503 error page is desired (disable browser's custom error page is needed as well).

Comment: Just updated the question. I did not know how to disable custom error page. I tried to open the website in the server (using remote connection) and opened it in localhost post, while uploading, but I did not get 503 error (browser trying to connect without dropping the connection), while from outside of the remote server users get 503 error.